# How to add environmental factors/explanatory variables to an ANOSIM test, following an NMDS

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to analyse the significance of species composition at three different sites in relation to environmental factors measured at each site. I have created an NMDS plot and then started to try and perform an ANOSIM test. I can only work out how to test the similarity between the three sites but not work out how to add environmental factors as a variable in the similarity.
species_ is my data frame containing only abundance
speciesdata_ is my data frame containing abundance and site and habitat as columns.

```
ano = anosim(species_, speciesdata_$Habitat, distance = "bray", permutations = 9999)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at some of the other functions available in the `vegan` package.

For example, `envfit` can be used to fit environmental vectors onto your NMDS plot.

The `adonis` function provides an alternative way to test which environmental variables are influencing the community structure.

Have a read through the `vegan` documentation and check the vignettes available on the `vegan` CRAN page:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/index.html